# Find the standard matrix of the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am given

Find the standard matrix of the linear transformation

T $\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\\z \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}x+z\\y+z\\x+y\end{bmatrix}$

All the online searches and such I look at give you T(e<sub>1</sub>)...T(e<sub>n</sub>)

I have no clue how to even start this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T=\matrix{{1 \;0\; 1}\\{0\; 1 \;1}\\ {1\; 1\; 0}}$$

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the answer?

Comment: write $T\array{x\\y\\z}$ with $T$ coefficients